# How to make existing data indexed by newly created index

Tags: riak, riak-search

I have created a new solr schema. I have created a new index from new schema. I have an existing bucket type where data exists. How will the existing data can be indexed with the new index created?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Active Anti-Entropy (AAE)](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/reference/search/#active-anti-entropy-aae) enabled on your Riak cluster, existing entries will be eventually picked up by the index.

Keep in mind that it may take a long time (depending on the configuration) until your index has been fully repaired.

[How to enable and tune AAE](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/cluster-operations/active-anti-entropy/), select the right Riak version.

Alternatively, you can [force a repair](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/repair-recovery/repairs/#repairing-search-indexes), or re-write the keys (read from a key and write the data back with the same key). Both depend very much on how many keys you have, and if you can tolerate the load it is going to create on your cluster.

**UPDATE**

There is a work in progress page in the Riak documentation repo that explains just that: [Reindex Existing Data](https://github.com/basho/basho_docs/blob/1131e0349aed89b0feea6774d006887496a7d041/content/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/cluster-operations/update-search-schema-reindex-data.md)

Comment: Does it answer your question? Were you able to achieve what you needed?